# Redis in Node.js: how to read Node Buffers

Tags: node.js, redis

Must be missing something here, but I'm using [Node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/) as Node.js client for Redis. 
I'm testing Redis' [Lrange](http://redis.io/commands/lrange) command which per that doc returns a 'multi-bulk reply'.

From the node_redis docs this gets exposed as a 'JavaScript Array of node Buffers' in Node.

That's all pretty and all, but what are node buffers and more importantly, how do I read them in Node.js? I just want to transform them to an array of string (json) and from there to an array of object literals.

For ref, grabbing the first element of the array `buffer[0]` and printing it (trying all kinds of things:

`console.log(multibulk[i]) -> [object Object]`
`console.log(multibulk[i].toString("binary")) -> [object Object]`

etc.

thanks.

**EDIT:** 
I verified the data is actually there in Redis (and is not stored as the String `[object Object]` as I began to expect). In Java when using JRedis' lrange command I get a List < String >. The first result of that list gives me the correct String as expected.

Comment: Did you try calling toString() with no parameters?

Comment: yes, exactly the same output. I'm starting to feel that it's something on the javas-side (where I stringofy objects to JSON and add them to the list in Redis).. What, I don't have a clue though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this:
as part of a kind of locking-mechanism I made sure a key was written to  in Node. Stupidly I did this by inserting an object literal without stringifying it. This caused all later inserts in the list to fail.